# Trigger a function when elements need re-rendered in an extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a function that positions an element in my Firefox extension, and I need that function to be called whenever an event causes the window/chrome layout to change.

Events would be:

1. When a new window is created, after the chrome is rendered.*
2. When a window is re-sized.
3. Any other event that might cause the chrome layout to change size or shape?

(*) Right now, the function runs when a new window is created using:

`window.addEventListener("load",myfunction);`

But this runs before the chrome is rendered, and element sizes have wonky values. I need it to run after Firefox determines the actual size and placement of the chrome elements.

What are the events I would need to bind to, and how do I bind them?

Answer (score 1):

1. I was in a similar situation, and didn't really find a good solution. However, the non-standard [`MozAfterPaint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/MozAfterPaint) event may help, but comes with a somewhat sizable performance penalty however (so make sure you remove it once you don't need it anymore).
2. The [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize) event should do the trick.
3. There are tons of things that may cause things to change. New CSS/Images loading, toolbar customization, etc. 1. and 2. should cover most (all?), however.

The `devtools layoutview` ("Box Model") seems to use `MozAfterPaint` as well.

If possible, you should try to avoid having to calculate sizes yourself, however, by making use of the XUL/HTML flexbox model and CSS without fixed sizes (or min/max sizes only).